# ArcGIS for Server printing error " Unsupported 'type' in symbol: esriCLS.\nLayer "

Tags: arcgis-server

If I have any polygon graphics in my graphics layer, my print task will not work. If I clear the graphics then it works.

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Error executing tool. Export Web Map Task Job ID: j7a98d1683c504a24a55024e9937412b5 : Layer \"map_graphics\": Unsupported 'type' in symbol: esriCLS.\nLayer \"map_graphics\": Unsupported 'type' in symbol: esriCLS.\nFailed to execute (Export Web Map).\nFailed to execute (Export Web Map Task)."]}}
```

The service will work if I add line or point  as graphic  to the graphics layer.

Answer (score 1):

I changed  definition of The line from

```
   var lineSymbol = new CartographicLineSymbol(
                                                    CartographicLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                                                    new Color([255, 0, 0]), 10,
                                                    CartographicLineSymbol.CAP_ROUND,
                                                    CartographicLineSymbol.JOIN_MITER, 5
                                                );
```

to

```
 var lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
                                    lineSymbol.setWidth(5);
                                    lineSymbol.setColor(new Color([230, 0, 0, 1]));
```

and it worked .